# Is the norm on $\ell^\infty$ induced by an inner product?

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, functional-analysis, normed-spaces, inner-products

Let $\ell^\infty$ be the normed space of all bounded sequences $x \colon= \left(\xi_n \right)_{n \in \mathbb{N} }$ of complex numbers, with the norm defined by 
$$\lVert x \rVert_{\ell^\infty} \colon= \sup_{n \in \mathbb{N}} \lvert \xi_n \rvert.$$

Is this norm induced by an inner product?

That is, can we show that 
$$\lVert x + y \rVert_{\ell^\infty}^2 + \lVert x - y \rVert_{\ell^\infty}^2 \ = \ 2\left( \lVert x \rVert_{\ell^\infty}^2 + \lVert y \rVert_{\ell^\infty}^2 \right) \ \ \ \mbox{ for all } \ x, y \in \ell^\infty?$$
Or can we find any bounded sequences $x \colon= \left( \xi_n \right)_{n \in \mathbb{N} }$ and  $y \colon= \left( \eta_n \right)_{ n \in \mathbb{N} }$ of complex numbers for which the above equality fails?

Comment: Just take $\mathbb{R}^2$, with $x=(1,0), y=(0,1)$.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

So I'm just elaborating on the comment by cobber.hat.

Take $x = (1,0,0, 0, \ldots)$ and $y = (0,1,0, 0, 0, \ldots)$. then:
$$\lVert x+y\lVert^2_\infty =1 \qquad 
\lVert x-y\lVert^2_\infty =1 \qquad 
\lVert x\lVert^2_\infty =1 \qquad 
\lVert y\lVert^2_\infty =1$$

Thus we have a counter example to your formula.

Comment: Agreed.  In $2$ dimensions, the unit ball of a norm induced by an inner product is an ellipse.  But in $2$ dimensions, the unit ball of $\ell^\infty$ is a square, not an ellipse.